# To change tomcat favicon when the application is deployed at Tomcat root

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, favicon

I have a web application and we have deployed that at Tomcat root. I want to change the default tomcat favicon with a different image.
I tried putting the icon at the webapps\ROOT folder but it is not working. I tried clearing browser cache too.
My application war is ROOT.war and it extracts into the webapps\ROOT folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you extract ROOT.war into webapps\ROOT, or did Tomcat? If Tomcat, then it likely resyncs the folder from the .war, so removes/ignores the file you added. Either *you* extract the .war and then add the file, or add the file to the .war file.

Comment: @Andreas Tomcat did the extraction, and once the war got extracted successfully, I copied the file in the extracted ROOT folder.